# lidR: What is "Area" in Cloud_metrics(.stdmetrics)?

Tags: lidr

I have plot locations and .las tiles.

I have extracted the point clouds at each of the plots with a 15 meters radius.
It means i now have as many .las files as i have plots.

Then, in a for loop, for each of the plot .las files, i have run cloud_metrics with .stdmetrics.

However, one of the metrics seems strange to me.
Area is defined in the documentation as the surface of the area of interest.
When i look at my values , i get areas between 750 and 850. **No units are specified in the documentation.**
It does not correspond so well to the area in square meters as it would be around 706 m², or less because the point are inside of that area.
Moreover, the area i get from this function seems quite variable, as i said, between 750 and 850.

I would like to get explanations on this: What exaxtly is Area when applied in cloud_metrics, what is its unit.

Finally, I just want to know one thing. I got sent a script where it is performed a ratio of areas between a file with only points above 5m and a file with all points, for the same location. What could that ratio mean when the area is supposed the surface of the AOI?

Comment: One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`area` is `(xmax-xmin) * (ymax-ymin)` i.e. the area of the bounding box of the points for a given level of regularization. It is not very useful by itself but might be useful if you look at the consistency.

For example in `pixel_metrics` with 20 m pixels you are expecting this metric to be consistently close to 400. If not it corresponds to some incomplete pixels which are not fully populated (typically on the edges of the raster).

With `cloud_metric()` and plots of 30 m diameter the expected value is 900. It might be smaller but if it is too small you may need to check your data to verify your plot is not missing some parts. For example a plot extracted on the very edge of the dataset may have missing part because of the absence of data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer :)